# Python yard-plot ROC curve generation incorrect

Tags: python, graph, roc, yard

I'm trying to graph the results of a binary classifier as a ROC curve (hit rate vs false alarm rate) using [yard-plot](https://github.com/ntamas/yard). The problem is that the graph does not reflect my data.

The command I call is:

```
C:\Python26\Scripts\yard-plot.exe -o E:\images\classifiers\roc_curve.png E:\images\classifiers\ROCData.txt
```

The input data "ROCData.txt":

```
output  GrayHistogramEqualization   NoPreprocessing
-1  0.853186    0.822022
-1  0.430748    0.422438
-1  0.178670    0.065789
-1  0.016620    0.010388
-1  0.000693    0.000693
-1  0.000000    0.000000
+1  0.993750    0.998750
+1  0.941875    0.950625
+1  0.840625    0.874375
+1  0.748750    0.787500
+1  0.670000    0.663750
+1  0.647500    0.657500
```

Each column is tab separated.

The current output "roc_curve.png": https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUpzW.jpg

Anyone know what could be causing this? Thanks.